# Giving a default permission for cache folder

Tags: symfony, caching, chmod

The problem is when I clear caches in my Symfony project on production environment, I should type this command for giving right permissions to cache folder:

cd app/cache

sudo chmod -R a+w *

But is there any way to not typing these commands each time?

Comment: did you read this part in docs - http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/installation.html#checking-symfony-application-configuration-and-setup ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
sudo setfacl -dR -m u::rwX app/cache
```